# Excel vba insert new row after a specific row based on how many rows from a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file, where i have set of 5 rows and it is named as "sale1" to "sales 5". This is what i am looking for in specific:
I enter a value between 1 to 5 in Cell C4,  I want a new row to be inserted after the row where it's currently written "Sales 5" (I have 5 sets of rows sets) so the macro needs to search for the key word "Sales 5" (every cell contains the text "Sales5") the new number of rows need to be inserted below that.

ex: I have entered the value "3" in cell C4, so the macro needs to look for the Key word "Sales5" and start inserting 3 new rows below that cell where it find the keyword "Sales5".

i am a beginner so not sure on the exact code

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: Please include the code you have so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your "Sales1" to "Sales5" values are in column A, try the below.

```
Sub sales_5()

Dim iInsertRows As Integer
Dim rg As Range

iInsertRows = Range("C4")

For Each rg In Range("A1:A100") 'Change this range to wherever you expect to find "Range5"
    
    If rg = "Sales5" Then
        rg.Offset(1).Resize(iInsertRows).EntireRow.Insert (xlShiftDown)
    End If
    
Next rg

End Sub
```